# why am i getting this "deprecated" error?

Tags: npm

explain it [my screensht](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJIrb.png)

i don't know  how to do it as i didn't know how to do it but i tried this 'npm audit fix --force' please help me
i get this error

```
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated opn@6.0.0: The package has been renamed to `open`
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.

changed 204 packages, and audited 205 packages in 9s    

2 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what’s wrong: some of your dependencies are too old or outdated and you should update them to newer versions.

Comment: First of all, there are no *errors* at all, just *warnings*.  You should try to update those dependencies to newer versions. But that may not always be possible, if they are included by some other package that may depend on a certain version of them ...

Comment: Note: these are _warnings_ not _errors_. The package will most likely work but npm is telling you that there are security risks involved with using it. It's up to the developer of that package to fix these issues. Check to see if there's been a more recent release, or whether any bug reports about these problems have been raised on the GH issues page. You may find that the package is dormant, and no further changes are likely in which case it's time to find a new package that mirrors the functionality.

Comment: what are dependencies...also how to update them ? @Terry

Comment: btw is there any alternatives to live server....in vscode extension and installing via npm

Answer (score 0):

**DON'T PANIC!** Just kidding of course...

`npm` has evolved during the years and protect it's users against potentials security risks. If the selected package is using old-versioned or risky dependencies, it may raise some warning regarding to the package integrity.  First let's have a look on the official [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server), and right up we see this:

> This is a little development server with live reload capability. Use
> it for hacking your HTML/JavaScript/CSS files, but not for deploying
> the final site.

Now, we instantly know that the main purpose of this package is to mimic a live server for web apps, as well as we know that the author himself does not recommend using this in production

Why does this matter? Well, if we intended to use it locally, and build our production project without it, there is a very small risk of using it locally (as long as your local build is NOT deployed from your machine to a remote machine / service)

If we want to take it on the safe side, a quick search (using `npm` search) will result with similar yet better supported packages like [livere-load](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload). Just compare the weekly downloads stats and how much dependencies it got (the more dependencies a package use - the more risk you'll have that some of them are outdated and may result with security risks) to get an educated guess whenever the package you are using is suitable for your needs or not

Cheers

Comment: so now what shld i do....also say how to download it

Comment: you may either use `pm audit fix --force` and keep your current package or `npm i livereload` (as mentioned in the package page) and see if that suits you better. Take your time to better understand each package and make your own decision. This is a crucial part of our job as software developers

Comment: i tried audit fix too

Comment: so.. you may consider using a different package after all :)

Comment: is tht safe to use?

Comment: please read my answer first, look at the packages stats as I requested and only then ask what you need if something is not clear enough. tnx

Comment: how to implement it??....i downloaded but how to use it ?

Comment: read the package documentation (link attached in the answer).. that is part of your job you know :)